# Alexa Skill request deserialization fails - json to SkillRequest object C#

Tags: c#, json, aws-lambda, deserialization, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to get some help here, I am using Alexa.NET nuget package to develop a custom alexa skill  using c#, I get the following error.

### My Request to the Function(AWS Lambda):

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.[unique-value-here]",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.[unique-value-here]"
    },
    "user": {
      "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.[unique-value-here]"
    },
    "attributes": {}
  },
  "context": {
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.[unique-value-here]"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.[unique-value-here]"
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {
          "AudioPlayer": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "LaunchRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.[unique-value-here]",
    "timestamp": "2016-10-27T18:21:44Z",
    "locale": "en-US"
  }
}
```

### The Deserialization Error:

```
System.Exception: Error deserializing the input JSON to type SkillRequest
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src142363207\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 214
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionRequest request) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src142363207\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 52
---------------- Inner 1 Exception ------------
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src142363207\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 202
---------------- Inner 2 Exception ------------
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.JsonSerializerException: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Alexa.NET.Request.SkillRequest: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'Alexa.NET.Request.Type.Request'
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
---------------- Inner 3 Exception ------------
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'Alexa.NET.Request.Type.Request'
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_DeserializeCreateObjectDelegateIsNull(Type invalidType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleStartObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ParseCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
```

### SkillRequest.cs(From Alexa.NET nuget package):

```
public class SkillRequest
    {
        public SkillRequest();

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("session")]
        public Session Session { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("context")]
        public Context Context { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("request")]
        public Type.Request Request { get; set; } //This is throwing the deserialization error
                                                  //See below for properties within this.

        public System.Type GetRequestType();
    }
```

### Request property type in SkillRequest above(this is where the problem is I think):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(RequestConverter))]
    public abstract class Request
    {
        protected Request();

        [JsonProperty("type", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("requestId")]
        public string RequestId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("locale")]
        public string Locale { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(MixedDateTimeConverter))]
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } // This might be the problem?
    }
```

I tried different DateTime formats, I played around by removing properties, to see if it goes past the deserialization error, nothing seems to be working. Can someone help?

Comment: I guess your `Request` class can't be `abstract` and must have public constructor

Comment: I made local copies of nuget classes, and removed the abstract keyword for the Request class and it worked. Thanks for your hint, if you can post your suggestion as an answer, I will mark it as the right answer. @vasily.sib

Comment: A public constructor was not needed though.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue, serializing JSON as per an Alexa tutorial I was following. This post helped me to resolve it, however, I was not comfortable with the idea of rewriting the Alexa.net class locally, as it was used this way in working tutorials I was following.

According to: [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-aws-lambda-supports-for-net-core-3-1/) From .net core 3 there is a new JSON serializer used in the templates. It provides a performance benefit, but also seems to introduce this error with Alexa.Net.

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializerAttribute(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
```

was replaced by

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]
```

The new serializer was throwing the 'parameterless constructor' error.  After installing the **Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json** package via Nuget, and referencing the previous version of the serializer referenced in the tutorials I was following, all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to chime in with what worked for me.

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API service I'm hitting from Alexa and was getting this same error.  I added a reference to NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson and then popped this into my Startup.cs file: `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` in the `ConfigureServices()` function.

Source: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/

Also looks like this was sort of reported as an issue
https://github.com/timheuer/alexa-skills-dotnet/issues/193